# Calculating age from date of birth with between condition on age

Tags: mysql

I'm calculating age using MySQL like this

```
SELECT timestampdiff(year, md.birthDate, curdate()) as age 
  from user 
 WHERE age BETWEEN 10 and 20
```

but I want to fetch data between to age and MySQL showing unknown column for 'age' so how I can set the condition?

Comment: You need `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`, as `age` will only be a column of the *result* (not the database itself). In simple terms, `HAVING` filters after selection, while `WHERE` does it prior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variant 1 (expression instead output name):

```
SELECT timestampdiff(year, md.birthDate, curdate()) as age 
from user md
WHERE timestampdiff(year, md.birthDate, curdate()) BETWEEN 10 and 20
```

Variant 2 (HAVING instead of WHERE):

```
SELECT timestampdiff(year, md.birthDate, curdate()) as age 
from user md
HAVING age BETWEEN 10 and 20
```